# How to handle json from http

Tags: c#, json, webclient

I use a WebClient class to nagivate to a website. it returns me a download dialog box to download the output in a json file. Issit possible to read whats in the json file without downloading it? i opened up chrome and pasted the same url and chrome showed me the output in the browser itself.

Comment: What do you mean by downloading? Saving to a file? In that case, yes, you can handle it without saving it to a file. If you mean by download what download actually means: How may you ask such a thing!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the content type and browser, content may be ***zipped*** in some instances. Stackoverflow API is one such example.

In these cases you need to set `request.AutomaticDecompression`. Below code might give you fair idea of understanding and to continue from there.

```
public string CallRequest(Uri url)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    var httpResponse = "";
    if (request != null)
    {
        request.UserAgent = "stackoverflow"; // just example.
        request.Accept = "gzip,deflate";
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {           
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                httpResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    return httpResponse;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. Able to get the content perfectly. May i know whats useragent for?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a request to the link and you will have the JSON in a string:

```
public static Response MakeRequest(string requestUrl){
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            throw new Exception(String.Format(
            "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
            response.StatusCode,
            response.StatusDescription));
        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
        object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
        Response jsonResponse
        = objResponse as Response;
        return jsonResponse;
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    return null;
}
```

}